# Replacing content in <p> in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

This is a jQuery function that should accumulate a variable called p1 or p2 depending on the class of the td clicked. It should then append this to the paragraphs `cheap` and `premium` depending on the class. The function to write to the class is at the bottom, although I feel that this might be incorrect since the variable in the paragraph probably won't update at the same time as the variable. Also the bottom function doesn't actually do anything.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('td img').click(function () {
     if ($(this).parent().hasClass('x')) {
     alert("Seat " + ($(this).parent().attr("id")) + " is taken");
        } else if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')){
     $(this).attr('src', 'images/a.gif');
     $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
 var z = $(this).parent().attr('id');
 $('#'+z+'1').remove();
     return false;
    } else {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('n')){
    p1=p1+1;                
    } else if ($(this).parent().hasClass('p')){
    p2=p2+1;
    }
$(this).attr('src', 'images/c.gif');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    alert($(this).parent().attr("class"));
var z = $(this).parent().attr('id');
$('<p>').attr('id', z+'1' ).text(z).appendTo('#order');
    return false;
       };
    });
  });

$(document).ready(function(){
$(p1' Standard seats= £'(p1*10)).appendTo('#cheap');
$(p2' Premium seats= £'(p2*20)).appendTo('#premium');
});
```

The mathematical operators appear to work, but what I'm looking for is a way to append `$(p1' Standard seats= £'(p1*10)).appendTo('#cheap');` or the premium equivalent without it adding a new paragraph each time-ie and overwrite or similar. `replaceWith()` doesn't appear to work either.

HTML added:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>Seat Booking</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='hall.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='hall.css'/>
</head>
<body>
<div id='content'></div>
<h1>Seat Booking</h1>
<div id='details'>
<div id='what'></div>
<div id='when'></div>
<div id='where'></div>
</div>
<div id='plan'>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td class='n' id='a1'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a2'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a3'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a4'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td></td>
   <td class='n' id='a6'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a7'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a8'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a9'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class='n' id='b1'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='b2'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='b3'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='b4'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td></td>
   <td class='n' id='b6'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='b7'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='b8'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='b9'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class='n' id='c1'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='c2'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='c3'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='c4'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td></td>
   <td class='n' id='c6'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='c7'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='C8'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='C9'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class='n' id='d1'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='d2'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='d3'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='d4'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td></td>
   <td class='n' id='d6'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='d7'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='d8'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='d9'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class='p' id='e1'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='p' id='e2'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='p' id='e3'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='p' id='e4'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td></td>
   <td class='p' id='e6'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='p' id='e7'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='p' id='e8'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='p' id='e9'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id='order'>
<h2>Order Summary:</h2>
</div>
<div id='subtotal'>
<h2>Total Price</h2>
<p id="cheap">hhh</p>
<p id="premium">jjj</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example (i.e. the HTML) and if possible, a jsFiddle.

Comment: -1 until you edit your sample code to only include the significant lines. Also fix your indentation!

Comment: Code indented and HTML added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you test this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var p1=0,
    p2=0;
$('#cheap').text(p1 + ' Standard seats= £' + (p1*10));
$('#premium').text(p2 + ' Premium seats= £' + (p2*20));
$('td img').click(function () {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('x')) {
        alert("Seat " + ($(this).parent().attr("id")) + " is taken");
    } else if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')){
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/a.gif');
        $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
        var z = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('n')){
            p1--;                
        } else if ($(this).parent().hasClass('p')){
            p2--;
        }
        $('#'+z+'1').remove();
    } else {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('n')){
            p1++;                
        } else if ($(this).parent().hasClass('p')){
            p2++;
        }
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/c.gif');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        alert($(this).parent().attr("class"));
        var z = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $('#order').append('<p id="'+z+'1">'+z+'</p>');            
    };
    $('#cheap').text(p1 + ' Standard seats= £' + (p1*10));
    $('#premium').text(p2 + ' Premium seats= £' + (p2*20));
    return false;
});
});
```

Edit:
A had some global variables to save the number (cheap and premium) of seat selected.

A move

```
$('#cheap').text(p1 + ' Standard seats= £' + (p1*10));
        $('#premium').text(p2 + ' Premium seats= £' + (p2*20));
```

in the click event

and a had this when a seat is unselected:

```
if ($(this).parent().hasClass('n')){
            p1--;                
        } else if ($(this).parent().hasClass('p')){
            p2--;
        }
```

**Edit 2:** 
interactive code:

http://jsfiddle.net/kdQmq/3/

Comment: This still adds a new paragraph each time, and it seems to add it with the same id as the one that's added to the order div with the td id in it

Comment: Substituted my code for the code above. Has same problems as my code

Comment: @Thomas that works, perfect. What did you change from my code?

Comment: Look my post. I add some comments

Comment: @Thomas Thanks very much, this is a great help!